# Django admin: the most proper way to limit choices of dropdown window?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I am trying to customize dropdown for one of my models named Recipe.

The problem is I do not want duplicates appear. Say, administrator selected choice X from the first dropdown, then he or she clicks on the second one but there are the same choices though. Because of it admin can create a recipe with two identical tags, for example, so I would want to deprecate this logic.

Comment: If you are aware of another way to implement "avoid duplicate" logic, please, let me know.

Comment: can you share some code of what you tried

Comment: I think it would be JavaScript solution, so if you can, please, provide another way to solve it.